# Extjs 5 listener stop working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have weird problem with Extjs 5.0.

I have a window :

```
Ext.define('xxx', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
// ...... //    

    items : [ {
        xtype : 'grid',
        reference : 'maingrid',
        bind : {
            store : '{users}'
        },
        flex : 1,
        selModel : Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
            mode : 'SIMPLE'
        }),
        listeners : {
            selectionchange : 'onSelectionChange'
        },
    } ]
});
```

The *selectionChange* event handler work perfectly for the first time.
But when I close the window and open again - this event handler stop working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please replicate the issue in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/).

Comment: As Digigizmo stated you can't say what's wrong based on the current code excerpt.

A typical problem is that the instance of the window is destroyed although it should be hidden. Try `closeAction: 'hide'` in the define of the window class.

Comment: It's too complicated to post this in the fiddle.
If I use 'hide' - it's work but I must close the window :(
Why window listeners still working after re-create but listeners for windows items not?

Comment: You asked 'What am I doing wrong'. Concerning the code excerpt above the answer has to be: nothing. But I assume that the error is in some  other piece of your code, likely at that point where you are creating and opening the window.

Comment: The difference between `hide` and `destroy` for `closeAction` is the effect on the instance of your window. The window is closed in either case.